# Why i have duplicates data in my HashSet?

Tags: java, hashmap, set, hashset

I'm trying to manipulate HashSet in Java. I saw that, normally, there are not duplicates possible in a HashSet ?

Here is my code

```
 public class A{
    private int elem;

    public A(int elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
    }   
}
```

And in another class

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class B{

    private String name;
    private HashSet<A> listeA;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashSet<A> a = new HashSet<A>();

        B s = new B("B",a);
        A l1 = new A(15);
        A l2 = new A(14);
        A l3 = new A(15);

        a.add(l1);
        a.add(l2);
        a.add(l3);

        s.displayHashset();

    }
```

So if the HashSet doesn't allow duplicates, why i have this after the execution of the code :

```
15 
15 
14
```

I don't understand how the second "15" can be accept in my HashSet..

Thanks for replies.

Comment: They are different objects, just have same attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't override the `equals()` and `hashcode()`. HashSet checks if an object is equal to another based on the equals method. Also, in order to not make to many comparisons, it groups objects with equal hashcode together.

Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

A generated version of equals and hashcode:

```
public class A{
    private int elem;

    public A(int elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        A a = (A) o;
        return elem == a.elem;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i had a look on this but can't understand, now it's clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` uses `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods to define duplicates. When you implement those methods you tell `HashSet` what you mean by duplicate instances of your class. default implementations of `hashCode()` and `equals()` inherited from `Object` class treat each instance of your class as a unique object so `HashSet` allows several instances with the same values for its properties

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i had a look on this but can't understand, now it's clear for me.